# Adjust for TV option missing in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: tv

I love Linux and Ubuntu and have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on 3 of my PC's on 23 April 2022 one of which is connected to a TV and has some over scan issues where the picture is too big for TV screen.
I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on an old spare PC today on 9th May 2022 using the exact same USB stick I used for my other PC's back in April and now there is a very handy "Adjust for TV" option available on the Display settings for this new installation. How do I get this "Adjust for TV setting" on my other PC's as this would be very handy?
I have fully updated all my systems but the "Adjust for TV" is only on the new installation and I would like to know if I can get it on my others without doing a full format and reinstall as I have set them all up now.
Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The option appears and disappears based on the display details reported back by the TV. I don’t think the option can be forced to appear. That said, if you can adjust the TV with the oversized image to use “Underscan” (via the TV settings menu itself, not inside Ubuntu), then you should see a better picture 

Comment: Hello thank you for quick reply. I should let you know on this spare pc I already had ubuntu 22.04 installed and it had no adjust for tv option. It had a 250gb hard drive. I decided to put a 500gb hard drive in it so I did and reinstalled ubuntu 22.04. But now it has an adjust for tv option when it did not have before? Its the same spare pc so why now has this handy option appeared? I thought it might be an additional update on install? Again any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Basically it seems "Adjust for TV" is for AMD cards only

Turns out the spare PC has an AMD graphics card and my other PC's have either Nvidia or integrated graphics cards. The "Adjust for TV" option only seems to appear for AMD cards as when I remove the AMD card and use integrated graphics on spare PC the "Adjust for TV" option is missing and then comes back when I put the AMD card back into the PC.
Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can recreate the "Adjust for TV" setting using the command line or a script:

Note that you must be using the Xorg display server instead of the default Wayland. You can choose the "Ubuntu on Xorg" session by logging out and then clicking the gear button after selecting your name on the login screen. Alternatively, you can follow this [How do I use X instead of wayland on 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410256/how-do-i-use-x-instead-of-wayland-on-22-04).

In the terminal, type `xrandr` to determine the outputs available on your system.
From the following sample output, HDMI-A-0 is the monitor output we will be using for the next commands.

> HDMI-A-0 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 392mm

Command to turn underscan on:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --set underscan on --set "underscan vborder" 54 --set "underscan hborder" 96
```

Command to turn underscan off:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --set underscan off
```

Note: The "Adjust for TV" setting uses overscan borders that are 5% of the current resolution's width and height. For the 1920x1080 display used in this example, 5% of 1920 is 96, and 5% of 1080 is 54 giving the hborder and vboarder values used above. You will need to adjust these values depending on your resolution or if you require more than 5% overscan borders.